# Cart Product Update using API (SOAP v1) only updates quantity but not subtotal or total?

Tags: magento-1.7, api, soap

I can successfully add a product in cart and then check the cart.info to verify it. However, if I update any product in cart, only quantity is changed but the rowtotal, subtotal remains same

Added a product A in cart with quantity 2. When I fetch the cart.info, it shows quantity of Product A is 2, unit price: $5, rowtotal: $10 and so on.

And after updating same product for same customer(with quantity 4), The cart.info shows:
Product A, quantity: 4, unit price: $5, rowtotal: $10. (Expecting rowtotal to be $20)

Same follows for the cart subtotal and Grand Total - Not updated.

`$proxy->call($sessionId,'cart_product.update',array($quoteID,$arrProducts));`

Strange thing is, after updating the product quantity using API, when I refresh the cart page (on website - frontend), I can see the correct rowtotal subtotal and grand total in cart.info

Now sure if anything is wrong in API?

Comment: There's some internal note on this (SUPEE-4632) - did you ever find a resolution or do you have more info?

Comment: I was not able to resolve the issue. I do not remember but I think I used SOAP version 2 as alternative (unfortunately, i do not have the code to cross-check). If someone is still facing this issue can get help from this link http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/66a10a0030e4/magento-update-subtotal-item.html.